# Intermittent connection errors to Windows SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012

At random times users will get the message below:

"ERROR SqlServerHelper:759 - Unexpected exception
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host *******, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."."

When the user immediately tried to reconnect the connection succeeds.

I am not seeing any obvious errors in the SQL logs and the Windows logs.

This is for windows server 2012 and windows SQL 14.0.3401.7.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

We tried rebooting the server and checking the tcp connection settings but none of these fixed the issue. We also increased the keep alive time from 30000ms to 1000000ms, still no change.

We also checked the logs through SQL management studio and didn't see anything that was happening at the times that users were getting this message.

Comment: Looks like a network problem. Maybe a loose cable, or a duplicate MAC address on the network, or a broken switch, router or socket.

Comment: @Charlieface Any advice on how to find the problem? Seems like it could kinda be anything.

Comment: Pretty much. Start by doing a non-stop ping test on the server and see if you are losing packets. Then if so, do a process of elimination to find the problem, starting with the physical cables.